# subset the data on or before six month advance from today pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
Unit_ID    Added_Date                   Status         
105        2019-10-02 08:14:16          Rented
106        2020-10-21 07:19:13          Rented
109        2020-03-02 07:18:19          Rented
108        2020-08-01 04:15:28          Vacant
100        2014-10-02 08:14:16          Rented
```

From the above data I would like to filter data on or before six month advance from today based on Added_Date column.

Expected Output:

```
Unit_ID    Added_Date                   Status         
105        2019-10-02 08:14:16          Rented
109        2020-03-02 07:18:19          Rented
100        2014-10-02 08:14:16          Rented
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with [`offsets.DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) for filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
today = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
offset = pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)

df = df[df['Added_Date'].between(today - offset, today + offset)]
print (df)
   Unit_ID          Added_Date  Status
0      105 2019-10-02 08:14:16  Rented
2      109 2020-03-02 07:18:19  Rented
```

For filter data before next 6 months before today use:

```
today = pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d')
offset = pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6)
df1 = df[df['Added_Date'] <= today + offset]
print (df1)
   Unit_ID          Added_Date  Status
0      105 2019-10-02 08:14:16  Rented
2      109 2020-03-02 07:18:19  Rented
4      100 2014-10-02 08:14:16  Rented
```

Comment: I would like to subset any date on or before today + 6 month

Comment: updated the example (input and expected output) for more clarity

Comment: @ jezrael, I am extremely sorry for confusion, My requirement - today is Jan-27-2020. I would like to filter the data anything before Jul-27-2020

Comment: @ALI - It is simplier, give me a minute

Comment: @ALI - do you think data between today (Jan-27-2020) and next 6 months (Jan-27-2020) ? So change first solution by `df = df[df['Added_Date'].between(today, today + offset)]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206717/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).